# how to write a batch file which can identify value from a text file and store that value in some other text file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

i have a text file which have some number content and string content,I want to write a batch which can identify number content and store the number content from each line in some other text file.

Comment: Please show us some lines to see if there is a pattern that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

This example will work for integer numbers between spaces.

Special caution must be put in text file, as behaviour for `"`, `<`, `|`, `>` and `&` may be unpredictable.

Some optimizations may be made having more information about text file.

```
For /F "Tokens=*" %%i In (TextFile.txt) Do Call :GetNumber %%i
GoTo :EOF

:GetNumber
If "%~1"=="" GoTo :EOF
Set Number=
Set /A "Number=1*%~1"
If "%Number%" == "%~1" Call :StoreNumber %Number%
Shift
GoTo :GetNumber

:StoreNumber
Echo %Number%>Number.txt
```